# Java Application accessing Android App in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In Eclipse, I have an android app and a Java Swing application that I run.  If they are both running from Eclipse, can I get access to the other and read objects from it?  This functionality is for development only and will not be used outside of eclipse.

I am aware of socketing in Java, but I would like to be able to read and modify variables on objects in runtime if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativelly, one could devise such a thing.

The Java app would need to be redesigned a bit, in a server-y way, to accept incoming pseudo-connections from a library.

The library which would expose the Android internals would have access to Android app via JNI. The said library would be compiled as a .SO file and included in the android app.

That being said, you would need to develop the said library to act as a bridge between your Java app, and your Android app.

Comment: Once I expose the Android internals with the JNI, how does the Java App get access to them.  The applications are still independent.  I guess I am confused about this part "The Java app would need to be redesigned a bit, in a server-y way, to accept incoming pseudo-connections from a library."

Comment: The Java app needs to behave like a server, via sockets, or text-files (XML, JSON, etc) and the library just needs to be the bridge - make sure that the actual Android values are serialized and sent to the Java app, and updating the Android values with the return values from the API (fake API) calls. 

Your "API" is the mechanism which pokes (changes) the values and returns the modified value, or returns the same input value if the value doesn't need to be poked (updated, changed) in the Android code.

I hope I made it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

if your only pourpouse is setting variable values on runtime just for development, the best option may be debug the app, and set breakpoints where you need to stop, set desired values and go on with the debug proccess

Comment: That is what I am doing, but there are lots of variables that may need to be tweaked.  I also would prefer not to have breakpoints because then I can't observe the changes live.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot read objects from your Android App with your Java app.

Why? Android runs in emulator, which is a whole different process than the one running your Java code. Lately, OSes tend to not let any process touch other processess's memory because, well, malware.

The only way your Java app could touch Android app is if it were the parent of the Android app's process. Which is not going to happen. (unless you make it so)

So you need to redesign both of your apps with that feature in mind, and use the Java app as a backend that your android app will communicate to all the time, and think of your Java backend as "the server" - meaning, what the server tells you to do, you do it no questions asked.

No, you may not also 'poke' values at runtime without a attached debugger.